# best way to sum many subcounts

Tags: python, counter

What is the most efficient equivalent to `functools.reduce(operator.iadd, ({info.foo : info.ct} for info in infos), Counter())`?

An `info.foo` is an `int` identifier, and an `info.ct` is an associated subcount.  The goal is to get total counts by identifier.

Comment: How about just one Counter and a for-loop?

Comment: Yes, much faster. What do you mean with those "restructions"?

Comment: Not necessarily in general. Depends on what you're doing. In this case you're doing very expensive stuff. It would be much less expensive if you used `iadd` instead of `add`, but it would still be much more expensive than the straight-forward simple thing you can do in a for loop. Not sure why you're talking about `update`, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight-forward loop solution:

```
ctr = Counter()
for info in infos:
    ctr[info.foo] += info.ct
```

Avoids the O(n<sup>2</sup>) you get by repeatedly adding counters as well as the constructions of all your little dicts and Counters.

Comment: I'm finding `reduce(operator.iadd, ({t.p: t.q} for t in tests), Counter())` to be faster. Does this seem wrong? (I see all the dict creations.)
Oh no, typo. You're right.

Comment: @Alan In my own testing, that's still much slower than mine. Could you share your testing, especially your `tests` data?

Comment: One last thing.  It seems that a `defaultdict(int)` may be adequate to my needs.  In any case, in the setting of the present question, it seems to be twice as fast. I am surprised by that. Should I be? Thanks!

Comment: @Alan Ah, yes, `defaultdict(int)` is even faster. If I remember correctly (and if things haven't changed), it's implemented in C while `Counter` is partially implemented in Python. Even if you do need a `Counter`, it might be faster to use a `defaultdict(int)` to do the above work and then convert to a `Counter` afterwards.